# protobuf-net core documentation / overview

Tags: protobuf-net

I am a very happy protobuf-net camper. So far I have been using regular protobuf-net with [ProtoMember], [ProtoInclude] and friends markup with great success.

However now I realise I need to move to protobuf-net core, pre-generating serialization classes, specifically to be able to execute in the AOT environment of Unity on iOS.

That is all groovy and I found some good pointers from speficically [this blog post](http://www.frictionpointstudios.com/blog/2011/3/31/using-protobuf-net-serialization-in-unity-iphone.html) and got started migrating my protobuf-net integration, however information on the subject is not exactly littering the interwebs - at least not to an extend covered by my google-fu.

As I run into one obstacle after the other, digging through source to try and figure out what is going on, I grow a bit frustrated. I could really use a sort of overview / intentions / guideline of protobuf-net core vs. the regular brand.

My latest encounter is the "Non-public type cannot be used with full dll compilation" limitation which seems at the moment somewhat arbitrary, but definitely quite annoying given the implications it has on my existing design (the very reason why I was glad to rid myself of the regular .net binary serializer in favour of protobuf-net).

Any experience sharing / postmortem or similar helpful resource would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Just for completion, here's my serializer generator tool so far: https://gist.github.com/AngryAnt/a19d8c67155163936aae

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that the article you link to is out of date: there is tooling in protobuf-net itself to help handle this scenario - the precompile tool. Please see http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/introducing-protobuf-net-precompiler.html

As for the restriction on non-public types: this limitation is not arbitrary: it is a part of assembly validation by the core .net runtime. A formal assembly cannot reference things that it is not allowed to. If it tried, it wouldn't pass validation. You can get away with some smoke and mirrors when running in-memory, but not as a dll.

However! There is still potentially an option here - in particular `[InternalsVisibleTo]`. I've already done some work to make the precompiler do things with this attribute. I suspect that if you are happy to nominate the serialization dll as "allowed", then either it will *already* work, or it could be tweaked to work. I genuinely cannot remember (without checking) whether this scenario was on of those included - but I *suspect* it was.

This is probably more of a discussion thing for protobuf-net itself, rather than a stackoverflow question.  It might be worth us taking it there instead.

Comment: Hey Marc. Sorry about the late response. I had not expected such a prompt response from you :) With regards to the non-public restriction, I'm sorry if I came off confrontational. I was thinking reflection would nullify the requirement, but I can see why it would make most sense to avoid depending on that. I had managed to miss your blog entirely in my googling. This is the primary go-to place for latest news and docs on protobuf-net? The precompiler does indeed sound like what I need. Where exactly are you suggesting we move the conversation? Thanks again :)

Comment: @AngryAny typically, at build time, just after you've built the DTOs; for example: `precompile {some path}\MyDto.dll –o:MySerializer.dll –t:MySerializer`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are responding to :)

Comment: @AngryAnt oh, I'm sorry. I misread the last line of your previous comment. My fault, sorry. If you have a specific example or any issues feel free to email me (see my profile page).

Comment: Hey Marc. I sent an email to that address on the 13th of June. Just wanted to verify that it went through? :)

Comment: @AngryAnt will reply to that